# Backbone nested model attribute change event handling

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Consider the following as a backbone model:

```
{
id : 1,
details:{
         name: 'test',
         age : 25
        }
}
```

We can track attribute changes by using:

```
this.model.on("change:attribute",this.render,this);
```

But this doesn't seems to work with the nested attributes. Any suggestion on how to handle the change of nested attributes. 
Being more precise, I want to handle the change of the `'age'` attribute event.

Comment: Backbone is not that complicated. Since `age` is not model field, it won't trigger any events in case of changing. But there is some plugins which allows to do that. https://github.com/afeld/backbone-nested

Comment: I also recommend this extension: https://github.com/kahwee/backbone-deep-model